# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError On Motorola Android 12

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

This crash is occuring 80% on Motorola device which are on Android 12 version. This info was available at Firebase Crashlytics

Full stack trace from Firebase is available at [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1saWk8UgC5Zj2LzvZZVBJAYQh0yZ6aWwJ/view?usp=sharing)

Any help or guide will be appreciated.